# Dimension of tensordot between 2 3D tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, dimension, tensordot

I have a rather quick question on tensordot operation. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to perform a tensordot product between two tensors to get the right output of shape that I want. One of the tensors is B X L X D dimensions and the other one is B X 1 X D dimensions and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to end up with B X D matrix at the end.

Currently I'm looping through the B dimension and performing a matrix multiplication between 1 X D and D X L (transposing L X D) matrices and stacking them to end up with B X L matrix at the end. This is obviously not the fastest way possible as a loop can be expensive. Would it be possible to get the desired output of B X D shape by performing a quick tensordot? I cannot seem to figure out a way to get rid of 1 of the B's.

Any insight or direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you ment a result of B X L since the matrix multiplication of 1 X D and D X L is of shape 1 X L and not 1 X D. If that is the case, please update the question with the right details.

Comment: @A.Maman Thanks for catching that. Updated my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One option

Is to use `torch.bmm()` which does exactly that ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html)).

It takes tensors of shape (b, n, m) and (b, m, p) and returns the batch matrix multiplication of shape (b, n, p).

(I assume you ment a result of B X L since the matrix multiplication of 1 X D and D X L is of shape 1 X L and not 1 X D).

In your case:

```
import torch
B, L, D = 32, 10, 512

a = torch.randn(B, 1, D)    #shape (B X 1 X D)
b = torch.randn(B, L, D)    #shape (B X L X D)

b = b.transpose(1,2)        #shape (B X D X L)

result = torch.bmm(a, b)

result = result.squeeze()
print(result.shape)
>>> torch.Size([32, 10])
```

#### Alternatively

You can use `torch.einsum()`, which is more compact but less readable in my opinion:

```
import torch
B, L, D = 32, 10, 512

a = torch.randn(B, 1, D)
b = torch.randn(B, L, D)

result = torch.einsum('abc, adc->ad', a, b)

print(result.shape)
>>> torch.Size([32, 10])
```

The squeeze at the end is in order to make your result of shape (32, 10) instead of shape (32, 1, 10).

Comment: This is exactly what I hoping for. Thank you kind stranger! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) to be the most intuitive way to perform tensor summations:

```
>>> torch.einsum('bld,bed->bd', x, y)
```

Which will have a shape of `(B, D)`.

Formulated explicitly, the operation performed here is equivalent to:

```
res = torch.zeros(B, D)
for b in range(B):
    for l in range(L):
        for d in range(D):
            res += x[b,l,d]*y[b,0,d]
```

<sub>Actually the second axis on `y` is also looped over, but the range is just `[0]`, since `y`'s 2nd dimension is a singleton.</sub>